# PHP pack and with variables

Tags: php, hex, pack

I'm not a programmer by trade, and my Google-fu is underwhelming today. I'm trying to write a small little program that takes in a CSV file with a list of hosts, usernames, etc and outputs that as hex to a file with specific padding and controls that are required by the program that I'm using to connect to those devices.

The problem is that the resulting file requires the length of each variable be calculated and pack doesn't like the formatting from dechex(). Below is a small sample of my code.

```
// Login
  $bindata .= pack('sX',0x01);
  $length = (strlen($username) + 6);
  $length = dechex($length);
  print '>>> DEBUG LOGIN LENGTH: '.$length."\r\n";
  $bindata .= pack('sX',$length); //hex  length of string +6 
  $bindata .= pack('sX',0x00);
  $bindata .= pack('sX',0x05);
  $bindata .= "login";
  $bindata .= $username;
```

The problem is that the $length can come out as "c" or as "11" and pack wants 0x0c or 0x11 and thus the result in my file is that it just outputs 00. Is there a better way to do this or a way to make $length be 0xXX. Or am I just and idiot using the wrong pack arguments?

I've been banging my head against a wall for the last hour or so, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The argument to `pack()` should just be the number. You don't need to convert it to hex before packing, that makes it a string.

Comment: That worked great. VERY, VERY, much appreciated!

For posterity the only change that was required was commenting out or removing the line:

$length = dechex($length);